# "Multiple serializers are not supported" configuration error in NServiceBus 4.0.4 during unit testing

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I am trying to unit test message handlers for NServiceBus 4.0.4. The bus is configured to use JSON serializer in the application using the `Configure.Serialization.Json();` method call.

Whenever I call the `Test.Initialize()` method from the unit tests assembly I get the following exception: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Multiple serializers are not supported. Please make sure to only enable one`

I tried calling `Configure.Serialization.Json()` and `Serializers.SetDefault<JsonSerialization>()` before calling the `Test.Initialize()` method without any success.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? All examples I see on the internet do not mention any `Configure` calls.

Comment: I think you found a bug, please report it to us, https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported previously [here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/pull/1492) and looks like it will be fixed in the next NServiceBus build (both 4.0.5 and 4.1.0)

A workaround is to explicitly disable the xml serializer when enabling the json one.

```
Configure.Serialization.Json();
Feature.Disable<XmlSerialization>(); // hack to make NSB unit tests work
```